# SwiftUI, List from the JSON file shows only the first element

Tags: json, swiftui, swiftui-list

**Help please with JSON to understand SwiftUI**
The json file reads and prints, but when you create a List, it reads only the first element .. What am I doing wrong ???

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var fetch = Fetch()
    
    public var body: some View {
      
//        Text(fetch.persons.description)
        List(fetch.persons){ user in
            Text(user.name)
            }
    }
}
```

[image: List]
[image: json.description]

Comment: Make sure the `id` property is set and is unique; otherwise, you can do something like `List(fetch.persons, id: \.self)`

Comment: @New Dev , I wrote     public var id = UUID() in model and  in View  -  List(fetch.persons, id:\.self){ user in
            Text(user.name)
            }. Xcode write me -Initializer 'init(_:id:rowContent:)' requires that 'LibraryElement' conform to 'Hashable'

Comment: Do you mean, you had it before? Or you did it now?

Comment: @New Dev, i did it now

Comment: Ok.. and it didn't solve the problem? (I also saw you changed your above comment. If you have the `id` property, you don't need to do `List(..., id: \.self)` - just keep it as `List(fetch.persons) { ... }`)

Comment: I solved this problem: in model - 'var id: UUID?' in ContentView: 'List(fetch.persons, id:\.name){ user in
            Text(user.name)
            }'

Comment: That would only work if names were unique... If you had two "Nikalay"s, then it would again break

Comment: @New Dev. I changed it in a JSON file, wrote 2 Nikolay's - it works!

Comment: It "works" as in it displays the elements, but it will "break" when dealing with animation of removal of non-uniquely identified elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List` works with objects conforming to `Identifiable`, and the `id` is used to identify each object uniquely, which is how a `List` is able to track insertions, removals and edits.

In your case, the `id` is `nil`, which breaks it.

Instead, make sure the `id` is uniquely identifying each object in the list:

```
struct Foo: Identifiable {
  var id = UUID()
  // ...
}
```

```
var foos: [Foo]
List(foos) { foo in 
   // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you'd need to provide a KeyPath to a property that can act as a unique id (and it needs to conform to `Hashable`), which could be the element itself.

```
struct Foo: Hashable { }
```

```
var foos: [Foo]
List(foos, id: \.self) {
  // ...
}
```